# PhD funding - other sources

Tags: phd, application, funding, research-assistantship

I found a lab offering the kind of research that I really want to do. I approached them and they were very happy to take me in. However, there is no funding and we all hoped I could get into a PhD programme at my university (their lab was on the list for rotation year). Sadly I was not selected for an interview, apparently the competition was very fierce this year. I contacted the lab again and now they are asking if I have other PhD funding? I wonder how I should reply to them, because I don't have any and I tried searching. From others I heard that you can get accepted and then look together for funding or there is a funding (the PhD programme that I was not selected for) and they just search for a suitable candidate. In my case they kind of ask me for the funding, is that right?

Self-funding would be very hard and I even tried looking if my country offers any government funding but I found none. I was told I could try getting maybe an assistant/technician job in their lab and hope that they might apply for grants? I'm very new to all the PhD issues so I'm not sure how I should deal with this but I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

They are asking if you are able to self-fund or if you have received any of the (extremely rare and competitive) bursaries/scholarships. It sounds like the university thinks you would be a capable student, but unfortunately the other new PhDs were considered more competitive than you in the eyes of whatever committee decides funding. These decisions are made by a university committee, so this does not reflect on your prospector's adviser's opinion of you (most of the time).

What country are you in? This is a very common thing in (e.g.) the UK for international students. I wrote a very extensive answer about this topic [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61795/fellowships-for-graduate-studies-in-uk-which-are-available-currently/61800#61800) although the advice is UK-centric.

If you managed to get an assistantship/technician job, it would have to pay well enough to pay both your tuition as well as a suitable salary for you if you have no other financial sources (jobs/loans/scholarships). I think that parallel teaching/lab jobs are commonly done in the US to fund PhD students, but I'm not sure whether it would pay 100% of your needs or not. If you're in the US, hopefully somebody more familiar with the American system will chime in here.

Personally, I would not recommend self-funding unless you are rich. If you are good enough to get a position here and to have an interested adviser, you shouldn't have trouble finding a paid PhD elsewhere. Alternatively, you could enquire about a full time position with the lab, and use the experience gained during that period to leverage your application in the next admission cycle.

If you think that your adviser intends to apply for a grant to fund you, you need to ask them. Basically at this point, go to your adviser for advice.

Typically, students apply to a range of universities so that when something like this happens, they have other options. To give you an example, I applied for 6 PhD programs in the UK and whilst I had offers for most, I ultimately could not get funding (my tuition alone would have been 22k per year) and went to Europe instead where everyone has an equal chance at being funded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I'm actually an EU student but I could be counted also as an international one (I have dual nationalities EU/Asia). I'm not sure if they are expecting me to have a funding secured or they just want to check whether I have something or not and then consider other options (maybe apply for grants?). I kind of want to ask them if they plan to apply for grants to fund me but I don't know if that doesn't sound rude/bold as if I expect that to happen? Well I hope since I was not able to secure a scholarship.

Comment: Just to clarify, the university is in the UK right? Or where?

Comment: Yes, the university is in UK.

Comment: Okay, that's good actually. What's your field? Also, you told the university you hold EU citizenship, yes?

Comment: It's Molecular Biology and yes I told them I'm EU.

Comment: For now I guess I will reply that I don't have other funding source for PhD and try to ask whether they might plan to apply for any grants to fund me - but should I ask straight away (can't help finding it rude) or gently hint on that? I don't want to write anything they might take as being not proper. Again, I have this strong sense of politeness hence why I find it a bit tricky writing to supervisors, some are easy to approach, some less. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know if ESPRC/STFC cover biology but I think they do. They fund almost everybody's PhDs in the UK. But those bodies (and others similar) cover the tuition fees of EU students, but not stipend. My old university matched the ESPRC/STFC contributions for students.

Are you replying to the university specifically or the adviser? I'd tell the university simply that you do not have other funding at this time, and ask them what your options are. Ask what you are eligible for given your nationality. Ditto the adviser really. Don't make assumptions but ask about your options / for advice. :)

Comment: If you feel that you need to specifically ask about a grant, I'd word it as "are there any other options that you are aware of? are there grants available for EU students?" rather than "are you applying for a grant for me?"

Comment: I've sent a message to my Czech friend who is doing his PhD in the UK. When he replies I'll let you know what he says.

Comment: To follow up: He is fully covered with tuition and stipend via STFC. He says you should get the same funding as UK students.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate that! I tried to apply for the PhD programme which was partly funded by university and by Wellcome Trust. Since I was not selected at all, this leaves the matter just between me and the lab of interest. I will check ESPRC/STFC right now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Picking up on an old comment, EPSRC (engineering & physical sciences) and STFC (mostly physics) won't fund most biology research - this would be under NERC (natural environment), BBSRC (biosciences), or possibly MRC (medicine), depending on the exact topic. There are seven research councils in total, all discipline-specific with some defined overlaps.

Comment: @Andrew is totally correct on that - I just didn't know the names of the funding bodies outside my field. I'd guess (but don't know) that the rules would be the same.